# What is the best way to promote Academia website in my University

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Does the community have standardised material or methods for promoting the site?
I would be interested in promoting it but have no idea about how to go about it.

Comment: You might want to have a look at: http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/questions/24/publicizing-the-site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it is an Internet thing, I think that you cannot do better than:

- send a link to this site to your colleagues or mailing lists,
- describe it your own words what's Academia.SE.